# GeoServer WMS crashes

Tags: geoserver, wms

I'm using WinXP (sp3), GeoSever 2.3.0 with JRE 1.6 and trying to get any layer displayed as WMS.  Using the Layer Preview feature of the GeoServer admin web interface (GeoServer/web), it causes GeoServer to throw an exception for any of the WMS formats.  This is with a fresh install of GeoServer. I have also tried JRE 1.7 with no change in behavior. Insight is appreciated.

```
Request: getMap
        Filters = null
        Palette = null
        Tiled = false
        SRS = EPSG:26713
        FeatureVersion = null
        Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=capitals]]
        Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@6f893642]
        MaxFeatures = null
        Bbox = ReferencedEnvelope[590223.4382724703 : 608462.4604629107, 4914107.882513998 : 4920523.89081033]
        RemoteOwsType = null
        RemoteOwsURL = null
        Env = {}
        FormatOptions = {}
        Angle = 0.0
        CQLFilter = null
        Elevation = []
        FeatureId = null
        StartIndex = null
        ViewParams = null
        Crs = PROJCS["NAD27 / UTM zone 13N",
  GEOGCS["NAD27",
    DATUM["North American Datum 1927",
      SPHEROID["Clarke 1866", 6378206.4, 294.9786982138982, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7008"]],
      TOWGS84[2.478, 149.752, 197.726, 0.526, -0.498, 0.501, 0.685],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6267"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4267"]],
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]],
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", -105.0],
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0],
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996],
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0],
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0],
  UNIT["m", 1.0],
  AXIS["Easting", EAST],
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","26713"]]
        BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
        Transparent = false
        SldBody = null
        ValidateSchema = false
        Sld = null
        SldVersion = null
        TilesOrigin = null
        Exceptions = SE_XML
        Height = 330
        Width = 938
        Filter = null
        Time = []
        Format = image/png
        Buffer = 0
        Request = GetMap
        RawKvp = {BBOX=590223.4382724703,4914107.882513998,608462.4604629107,4920523.89081033, VERSION=1.1.0, FORMAT=image/png, SERVICE=WMS, HEIGHT=330, REQUEST=GetMap, LAYERS=sf:bugsites, STYLES=, WIDTH=938, SRS=EPSG:26713}
        Get = true
        BaseUrl = http://localhost:80/geoserver/
        RequestCharset = UTF-8
        Version = 1.1.0
08 Apr 10:21:34 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.geotools.image.ImageWorker
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.PNGMapResponse.formatImageOutputStream(PNGMapResponse.java:117)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapResponse.write(RenderedImageMapResponse.java:122)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:919)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:27)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:45)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:49)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
        at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:46)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:103)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:75)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:47)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:828)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
        at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this.  Apparently Oracle has decided not to distribute PYCC.pf with the JRE and is only distributed with the JDK.  I put a copy in the jre\lib\cmm directory and WMS started working.  Perhaps GeoServer installation should add this required file since the JRE no longer does.